# TabLayout Android, How to fill entire screen width with a few tabs & scroll with large of amount tab?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-tablayout

Please show me how to resolve this problem,
I want all tabs will spread to entire screen width in case have a few tabs, but auto matic scroll in case have many tabs.
How to detect have a tabs is out of display screen in scroll mode ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`TabLayout` has a field named `tabMode` if you want it to be scrollable then set is to `TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE`

Here is the full doc

```
/**
 * Scrollable tabs display a subset of tabs at any given moment, and can contain longer tab
 * labels and a larger number of tabs. They are best used for browsing contexts in touch
 * interfaces when users don’t need to directly compare the tab labels.
 *
 * @see #setTabMode(int)
 * @see #getTabMode()
 */
public static final int MODE_SCROLLABLE = 0;
```

I would also suggest you not to make the mode scrollable unless you have a minimum of 6 tabs

Comment: Thank Gil Goldzweig, but list of tabs in this case are dynamic, do you have more suggestion ?

Comment: You can change it dynamicly

Comment: But I don't know when tabs are small or large than screen size to choose correct mode

Comment: You just need to check the amount of tabs not the actual size of the tabs in pixels or something similar

Answer (score 0):

If you want the tabs to be occupied the fullwidth of the screen, you need to assign app:tabGravity=”fill” to TabLayout. If there are three tabs it will adjust in the screen bounds if more than three then it automatically give a scroll functionality

Rest please refer the link for complete tour of tablayout

https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/